# Create HTML page from MySQL to send to chromecast?

Tags: php, html, mysql, chromecast

I created a form to submit and store in a MySQL database and all is well. I want to take that data and create a static HTML page by fetching two of the rows. The HTML page can then be picked up by Chromecast and displayed on a TV monitor.

My problem lies with figuring out how to make the static HTML page. I can't seem to find anything to work exactly the way I want it to and haven't been able to come up with anything to work so far. I'd appreciate any help or a point in the right direction.

HTML Form

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Screen </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Screen Display Information</h3>
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
  Project Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="project_number" required><br>
 
  Customer Name:
  <input type="text" name="customer_name" required><br>
 
Machine Type:<br>
  <input type="text" name="machine_type" required><br>
 
Bay Number:<br>
  <select name="bay_number" required>
 <option value="bay1">Bay 1</option>
 <option value="bay2">Bay 2</option>
 <option value="bay3">Bay 3</option>
 <option value="bay4">Bay 4</option>
 <option value="bay5">Bay 5</option>
  <option value="bay6">Bay 6</option>
  </select><br>
  
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP saved as `thankyou.php`

```html
<?php

 
require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();


$project_number    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['project_number']);
$customer_name   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_name']);
$machine_type    = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['machine_type']);
$bay_number = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['bay_number']);
$query   = "INSERT into tb_bayform (project_number,customer_name,machine_type,bay_number) VALUES('" . $project_number . "','" . $customer_name . "','" . $machine_type . "','" . $bay_number . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);
 
if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
 
}
 
echo "Thank you, your changes have been recorded <br>";

 
$conn->close();
 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by make a static html page. There are numerous methods to do this. Programmatically in php you can write to a file using a file stream. What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: the code sample you've provided is to save some info to a database. Are you asking how to re-display that data on another page? (BTW, if you use PHP to generate some HTML, possibly with some variable elements like data from a database, then by definition it's not static. Static would be a file that is identical every time it's loaded and never changes. I don't get the impression that's what you want here).

Comment: Thank you, apologies if I'm not being clear. I tried generating an html page with $newfile after submitting by trapping the output, which worked, but it only creates an html file with the info just submitted. You are right about it not being static, it would be dynamic since it could change, I wasn't thinking of it that way. At any rate, I want to take the data from two rows in the db and display in an html file because I want to display, for example, info for Bay 1 & 2 on a screen, then Bay 3&4 on another screen.